# How to choose the right image size for UI design

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, android-image

I am new to Android and I need some advice on how to work with images.

1. I have a button which layout_width is match_parent. The button has rounded corner. So what image size should I choose to render the button so that in all devices it will look fine? Note: on this button I can't use 9 patch images. I don't want to use a 9 patch.
2. When I set my logo in a listview it is stretched and it appears very ugly. Let's say the image size which comes from server is 400x400 px wide. What should I do to scale the image to look fine in all devices?

Comment: attach how the logo appears as streched..

Comment: Are you using button tag? If you want to display image in the button, you better use imageview and make the image you want to use as button as background.

Comment: let's say I have green gradient background which corners are rounded. I want button looks fine in all device

Comment: Yes. As described below resolution, make image button to the standard resolution. That will work. Since android devices vary in resolution, below are the standards which most of the mobile uses.

Comment: according your answer I have to create 4 types of button and put it in ldpi,mdpi,hpdi,xhdpi folder?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Google for most standard screen resolutions of mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You can baseline the image sizes for a particular resolution, say mdpi.
Then scale the images for other resolution as,

```
ldpi = mdpi*0.75
hdpi = mdpi * 1.5
xhdpi = mdpi * 2
```

NB- Use 9 patch images wherever possible to avoid this overhead of creating multiple images.

Comment: in this point I can't use 9 patch images for some reasons. let's say I have button and I want put background gradient image. What size should I create my image to work fine to all devices.

Comment: without using 9 patch , the only way to go, is creating multiple size version of the same button image(based on the points in my answer) and put them in their respective resource folders.